# JavaFX scene stylesheets stop working after updating to jre 8u66

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have swing application which has panel that contains several JavaFX AreaCharts (using javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel) with custom styles. We had used a jre 8u20 and jre 8u25 and all worked fine, now I had to update to jre 8u66 and the custom styles just not working any more.

Custom style sheet added to scene using absolute file path like that:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///F:/_workspace1.8/conf/module/performance/styleServiceGeneral.css");
```

Custom css file (removed styles for lines 6-13 they are identical to styles for lines 4 and 5):

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.default-color0.chart-area-symbol{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0);
}
.series0.chart-series-area-line{
    -fx-stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.series0.chart-series-area-fill{
    -fx-fill: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.default-color1.chart-area-symbol{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0);
}
.series1.chart-series-area-line{
    -fx-stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.series1.chart-series-area-fill{
    -fx-fill: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.default-color2.chart-area-symbol{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.series2.chart-series-area-line{
    -fx-stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.series2.chart-series-area-fill{
    -fx-fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.default-color3.chart-area-symbol{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.series3.chart-series-area-line{
    -fx-stroke: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.series3.chart-series-area-fill{
    -fx-fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* black */
.chart-area-symbol.series4 {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.chart-series-area-line.series4 {
    -fx-stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.chart-series-area-fill.series4 {
    -fx-fill: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0);
}
/* green */
.chart-area-symbol.series5 {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(51, 255, 0, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.chart-series-area-line.series5 {
    -fx-stroke: rgba(51, 255, 0, 1);
}
.chart-series-area-fill.series5 {
    -fx-fill: rgba(51, 255, 0, 0);
}

.tooltip {
    -fx-background-color: #FFC800;
    -fx-text-stroke: #000000;
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was due to this line in CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
```

it doesn't required any more.